# Fill a <input> with a script in my toolbar

Tags: javascript

I want to fill an *input* from a *form* with a script (using JavaScript) in my toolbar (Firefox).

Example : (i use Google input)

```
<input type="text" name="q" />
```

My Script :

```
javascript:(document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value = "New Value");
```

But, when i click on the button, in my toolbar, the script don't till the *input* (on Google), just open a page with "New Value".

It's possible to do this ? if yes, how can i ?

Comment: By "toolbar" do you mean the URL bar, or via an extension? If URL, I seriously doubt it. (And why would you want to?)

Comment: Be more descriptive or add some example snippet using jsfiddle

Comment: I don't how to more descriptive , i have create a video, more simple : https://sendvid.com/lhd0v61o (i want this, just for test ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the script in an [anonymous function](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154) insulates it from code currently on the page.

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value%20=%20"New%20Value";})();
```